# PDO response to json

Tags: php

Im new to PHP and trying to make a very simple api (good way too learn i think), why doesnt this work?
When loading this page the output is: ***{"queryString":"SELECT id, Name FROM Food WHERE userID=1 ORDER BY Name"}*** and not the JSON-string that I want

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$response = $dbh->query("SELECT id, Name FROM Food WHERE userID=1 ORDER BY Name");

$responseJSON = json_encode($response);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo "$responseJSON";

$dbh = null;
```

Nothing is wrong with the query because i get what i want when trying this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$response = $dbh->query("SELECT id, Name FROM Food WHERE userID=1 ORDER BY Name");

    foreach ($response as $row)
        {
            print $row['Name'] . ' ';
        }


$dbh = null;
```

outputs:
*Bacon
Cheese
chips*

Comment: PDO query returns PDOStatement object what you need to execute.

Comment: 1st var_dump($response); this is PDOStatement which is converted to JSON. What Yo uwant to do is to agregate results to array, and then json_encode array with data from query.

Comment: it works with what @Dutow said, but when looking in developertools i see that a whole html DOM is output, with my json in the body-tag.. why is that? i only have code in <?php ?> and im setting header: header('content-type: text/json charset=utf-8');
please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$dbh->query retuns a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object, not the rows. To add the rows to the json, call [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) on the object.

```
$response = $dbh->query("SELECT id, Name FROM Food WHERE userID=1 ORDER BY Name")->fetchAll();
```

You may also specify the fetch mode, e.g.

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```